# NAND Flash interfacing ARM9 MTD partition not getting generated

Tags: memory, embedded, arm, embedded-resource, embedded-linux

I am developing an application on ARM9 based board using UBUNTU 10.04 and GCC as a compiler.

Previously I have interfaced the NAND flash from STMicroelectronics ( NAND512W3A25NB ). It is of 64MByte. It has a pagesize of 512Kbit.

With this NAND my application is working very fine.

Due to some upgradation of the memory requirement I need to switch to a bigger NAND flash memory which is from Micron ( MT29F2G08ABAEA ). It is of 256MByte and has a pagesize of 2048Kbit.

With the changes my board is not booting up.

I got the manufacturer ID as well as Chip ID. But MTD partitions are not getting generated.

After some searching I found there is some problem regarding the PAGE_SIZE.
I do not know how to solve this problem as i went through the linux/include/mtd/nand.h it has a MAX_ALLWABLE_PAGE_SIZE is of 8216 and it is also within m requirement, so i can not exactly getting the point that where i am going wrong ??

Comment: I found something there in kernel the timing of the NAND which are by default set.  You can check this by go through the /linux/arch/arm/mach-davici/board-da850-evm.c file.I am using AM1808 ARM9 based MicroProcessor.

Answer (score 3):

I use the same chip, *Micron MT29F2G08ABAEA*,  on an IMX25 design.  The chain *mtd->ubi->ubifs* are quite happy with this chip set.  Our differences are the [NAND flash controllers](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/mtd/nand) and their configuration.

The *Micron* chip has *sub-pages* and your controller may not support that.  Searching through [davinci_nand.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/mtd/nand/davinci_nand.c), I don't see any *sub-page* handling.

For the *MXC Nand* controller, we are using `hw_ecc`, `flash_bbt`,  and a `width` of one.  The *Micron* chip is only *8-bit*, although there are some *16-bit* versions like *Micron MT29F2G16ABAEA*.  Make sure the geometry is correct.  I think the Linux MTDs supports several chips in parallel.

It is quick to verify if that part is faster or not with the data sheets.  I suspect the *ST* part is slower than the *Micron* part and timing is not your issue.

Timing analysis of the *Micron MT29F2G08ABAEA* indicated that the IMX25 NAND flash controller was actually the bottle neck.  The *Micron* Flash seems quite fast.  It is either a bug in the *NAND controller* or more likely a configuration issue.

Some other information that is helpful (for you or someone to help you),

- Some `dmesg` or *console* output.
- A link to data sheets.
- The exact *NAND controller* used.
- The **platform data** or **DT** info used.
- `grep '^[^#].*MTD' .config` or *MTD* related configuration.

I don't think anyone can answer your question out-right, but I am glad to be surprised.

Comment: Ok  I found I was wrong at the Block Size settings so I changed it. I got the solution.

Comment: As I am fetching my Environment variables from the U-Boot. So I needed to make changes in the U-boot as well as Changed the U-boot-header file for the NAND Pagesize according to your NAND.

Comment: @ParthivShah: If an answer is sufficient in your opinion, you can click the **checkbox** under the up/down arrows for that answer.  Sometimes, people wait some time as better answers may be received.  I see you have accepted no answers to any of your questions, so I think you might not know about this?